# A voting system with jQuery, PHP and Smarty

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty, vote

I have made a voting feature to my website using only PHP and Smarty.
This's the HTML part of it:

```
<p>{$vote} <a href="vote.php?q_vote=vote_up&question_id={$qid}"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a> <a href="vote.php?q_vote=vote_down&question_id={$qid}"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a></p>
```

The PHP part of the code takes the vote and refreshes the same page.

I want to do the same thing using jQuery so that it won't need to refresh the page. Here is what I wrote in the HTML :

```
$("#q_upvote").click(function()
    {
        var vote = "vote_up";
        var votedata = "";
        votedata = "vote= " + vote;
        $.ajax({                 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vote.php',
                data: votedata,
                success: function(vote_msg){
                if(msg == 'ok')
                    {
                    //show the new vote 
                    }
                                        else
                                        //show notification
                }
    }
)
</script>
```

I couldn't figure how to show the new vote there. Can you help me with that? Also I appreciate if I'm told that if I'm going on the right way.

Comment: what is the ajax response new vote count or what?

Comment: You need to change the php response to not give a full page, but instead just give the single piece of information that you're looking for.  (Or a json string of several pieces of information).

Comment: you have in function vote_msg param but you check msg param change it. Also this line data: votedata, can be changed to data: "vote=voteup" this will simplify your script and you don't need so many variables. When you provide vote param to vote.php what does php file returns?

Comment: @RobertPodwika I haven't written that part yet but I think it should return a JSON variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Corrected your html code so that you have a placeholder for the
  number of votes.
- Corrected the Ajax call so that it passes the same parameters as per 
  the hrefs in your initial upvote anchor.
- Fixed various syntax errors in the ajax call

**Html Code**

```
    <p>
       <span class="votenumbers">{$vote}</span> 
       <a id="upvote_{$qid}" class="q_upvote" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a> 
       <a href="vote.php?q_vote=vote_down&question_id={$qid}"><i class="icon-thumbs-down</i</a>
   </p>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(".q_upvote").click(function()
    {
        var vote = "vote_up",
            question_id = this.id.split('_')[1], 
            votedata = "q_vote="+vote+"&question_id="+question_id;
        $.ajax({                 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vote.php',
                data: votedata,
                success: function(vote_msg){
                   if(vote_msg== 'ok')
                       {
                       //show the new vote
                       $(this).find('.votenumbers').closest().html(parseInt($(this).find('.votenumbers').closest().html())+1) 
                       }
                   else{
                        //show notification
                   }
                }
           });
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for such an answer. I couldn't understand this line : 
`var question_id = this.id.split('_')[1];`

Comment: In this context `this` refers to the anchor which has been clicked. So the id(`upvote_{$qid}`) is being `split` by the character `_`, then the `[1]` takes the 2nd element in the `array(['upvote','{qid}']`, returned by the `split` function, which is `$qid`. U gotta play with it to see for yourself :)

Comment: this line doesn't work :
`$(this).find('.votenumbers').closest().html(parseInt($(this).find('.votenumbers').closest().html())-1)`

Comment: You can try this `$(this).prev().html(parseInt($(this).prev().html)()+)1)`

Answer (score 0):

At the point you know that the vote has been saved correctly, you can just increment your vote on the client side, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var votes = 0;
$("#myVoteNumberDiv").html(votes);
</script>
```

At the point `//show the new vote` you'd write:

```
votes++; //or in case he voted down: votes--;
$("#myVoteNumberDiv").html(votes);
```

Tell me if you meant something different, I'm not completely sure I understood your question correctly.

Comment: he uses juery and you give him pure js :) ?

Comment: @RobertPodwika just to show the concept ;D but you're right, I changed it.

Comment: You changed it and it's even more worse. simply $("#tag").html(votes) and by the way --votes is faster than votes-- :)