# AJAX code to insert, update and delete items of database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

[image]

I have this dropdwonlist, this numbers are votes, my cuestion is very simple: how I can do that by pressing "-" remove the vote of database, and when I press any other number, the vote will update in the database with this value?

The default value of the dropdown list is `votacion.votCalificacion` which is the value of the vote in the database

This is the dropdownlist of votes:

```
<form id="post">
    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
        <option value="-1" selected>{{ voto.votCalificacion }}</option>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

This is the controller's function to manage votes:

```
public function gestionarVotoAction($pysStr, $votCalificacion)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pys = $em->getRepository('PYSBundle:Pys')->findPys($pysStr);
    $usuario = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $voto = $em->getRepository('UsuarioBundle:Usuario')->findVoto($usuario, $pys);

    if(!$voto) 
    {
        $voto = new Voto($usuario, $pys);
    }

    if ($votCalificacion == "-") 
    {
        $em->remove($voto);
    }
    else
    {
        $voto->setVotCalificacion($votCalificacion);
        $voto->setVotFecha(new \DateTime("now"));

        $em->persist($voto); 
    }

    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('usuario_pelicula', array('pysStr' => $pysStr)));
}
```

Comment: I think if you bind (by jQuery, for example) cd-dropdown change event to a AJAX function that takes it's selected value and process it in an action where you update the vote... It could work, isn't it?

Comment: Por cierto, paisano, la explicación te la doy también en castellano si quieres ;)

Comment: @daniSancas muchas gracias! El tema es que soy nuevo en esto, y no tengo mucha idea de JS, si hubiese algún ejemplo que me ilustrase con lo que me dices, te lo agradecería horrores!! :)

Comment: Te escribo una respuesta entonces, pero en inglés para que la puedan aprovechar otros también. Dame unos minutos ;)

Comment: What are you sending through the `$pysStr` var? Can you copy your `Pys Entity` and it's `Repository`?

Comment: @DaniSancas `$pysStr` is like slug

Comment: Isn't better to send the `$pysId` and use find by the ID instead a slug that might be duplicated (many films or series are equally named)? Secondly, it seems to be a problem with the `Voto Entity` and maybe the Doctrine Query is unable to retrieve it. Can you paste your `Voto Entity` too?

Comment: @DaniSancas Yes, I know but I had a problem developing iOS app, when I was parsing the id, it only worked with the slug. It's a minor bug that I have pending;)

Comment: Related to this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html I think you'll need to change your `Voto __construct()` method ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33245/discussion-between-dani-sancas-and-benatespina)

Comment: @DaniSancas I don't know if you read the last chat message in yesterday; now imports work fine and only need an AJAX function to do what I want. I just modified the question code; I've added the dropdownlist code in my template and the controller's function to manage the votes. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We can continue chating whenever you want. We have a little code left ;)

Comment: When you want, I'm in chat now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can take an example:

[A voting system with jQuery, PHP and Smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482081/a-voting-system-with-jquery-php-and-smarty)

And, to manage jQuery properly, here you have a couple of functions you may know:

**jQuery.ajax()** for AJAX petitions
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**jQuery.load()** for AJAX petitions which result in a new loaded content somewhere in your page
http://api.jquery.com/load/

**EDIT:**
After a couple of chat sessions, here goes the answer:

```
$('#cd-dropdown').bind("change", function(){ 
  ajaxVotar($('#cd-dropdown').val(), $('#id-pelicula').val()); 
}); 


function ajaxVotar(voto, pelicula) 
{ 
  $.getJSON('/app_dev.php/es/user/pelicula/'+pelicula+'/'+voto, function(j){ 
    alert(j.result); 
    $('#votacion-media-peli').html(j.media); 
    // Customize whatever you want...
  }); 
}
```

The whole chat session here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33245/discussion-between-dani-sancas-and-benatespina

Comment: I keep looking and I'm going crazy, there is another way? with forms perhaps? Like birthday fields when you update the user profile.
I guess I will have to create dql statements (insert, update and delete) in the repository...

Comment: Well, let's going with the easy part, and then I'll help you with the hard one. I need you to create an action to register vote, with a route like this: `/whatever/article/{id}/{score}` where `{id}` is the id of entity (article, producto, whatever) and {score} is the vote number (1, 2, 10, whatever), and make it work. (For example you can create a link and, when you click, you register that vote). Then I'll show you how to transform that into AJAX.

Comment: I'm doing the example what you say but my entity `Voto`has composite foreign primary key, with `Usuario` and `Pys` (Películas y series). I think I have a good implementation of the controller but displays an error (I've edited the question with the new code). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
first assign object

if(new add)
{
$oArticle  =new article() 
}
else
{
$oArticle  =$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArticleBundle:Article')->Find($id);
}
$oArticle->setField($field);
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($oArticle);
$em->flush();
```